# Use jquery to modfiy .css height or width based on which is greater

Tags: jquery, css, height, width

I'm new to jquery and html in general, and am working on building a gallery webpage.  This webpage works by setting the selected image as page background and then scrolling along the image vertically based on the vertical position of the mouse pointer.  This works great for images that are taller than they are wide, but a lot of my images are wider than they are all, so I also need it to work the other way and scroll left to right if the image ratio calls for it.

I'm trying to use a if, else if statement to determine whether I set the height or width to 100% in the .css.  Here's the bit of coding I'm trying to use, it isn't working:

```
$('<img class="fp_preview"/>').load(function() {
    var $newimg = $(this);
    var $currImage = $('#fp_gallery').children('img:first');
    if (newimg.width() > newimage.height()) {
        jQuery('#fp_preview').css({
            height: "100%",
            width: ""
        });
    }
    else if (newimg.height() > newimage.width()) {
        jQuery('#fp_preview').css({
            height: "",
            width: "100%"
        });

    }
    $newimg.insertBefore($currImage);
    $loader.hide();
```

There are close brackets and such after this, that's not he problem.  I've added the if statements using code I've found on this site to try to achieve the desired result.  fp_preview is the portion of the .css that displays the background image.

If anyone know how to do this, I would really appreciate the help.

Here's the full code and the .css portion I'm trying to modify:

```
<script type = "text/javascript" > 
$(function() {
    //current thumb's index being viewed
    var current = -1;
    //cache some elements
    var $btn_thumbs = $('#fp_thumbtoggle');
    var $loader = $('#fp_loading');
    var $btn_next = $('#fp_next');
    var $btn_prev = $('#fp_prev');
    var $thumbScroller = $('#thumbScroller');

    //total number of thumbs
    var nmb_thumbs = $thumbScroller.find('.content').length;

    //preload thumbs
    var cnt_thumbs = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < nmb_thumbs; ++i) {
        var $thumb = $thumbScroller.find('.content:nth-child(' + parseInt(i + 1) + ')');
        $('<img/>').load(function() {
            ++cnt_thumbs;
            if (cnt_thumbs == nmb_thumbs)
            //display the thumbs on the bottom of the page
            showThumbs(2000);
        }).attr('src', $thumb.find('img').attr('src'));
    }


    //make the document scrollable
    //when the the mouse is moved up/down
    //the user will be able to see the full image
    makeScrollable();

    //clicking on a thumb...
    $thumbScroller.find('.content').bind('click', function(e) {
        var $content = $(this);
        var $elem = $content.find('img');
        //keep track of the current clicked thumb
        //it will be used for the navigation arrows
        current = $content.index() + 1;
        //get the positions of the clicked thumb
        var pos_left = $elem.offset().left;
        var pos_top = $elem.offset().top;
        //clone the thumb and place
        //the clone on the top of it
        var $clone = $elem.clone().addClass('clone').css({
            'position': 'fixed',
            'left': pos_left + 'px',
            'top': pos_top + 'px'
        }).insertAfter($('BODY'));

        var windowW = $(window).width();
        var windowH = $(window).height();

        //animate the clone to the center of the page
        $clone.stop().animate({
            'left': windowW / 2 + 'px',
            'top': windowH / 2 + 'px',
            'margin-left': -$clone.width() / 2 - 5 + 'px',
            'margin-top': -$clone.height() / 2 - 5 + 'px'
        }, 500, function() {
            var $theClone = $(this);
            var ratio = $clone.width() / 120;
            var final_w = 400 * ratio;

            $loader.show();

            //expand the clone when large image is loaded
            $('<img class="fp_preview"/>').load(function() {
                var $newimg = $(this);
                var $currImage = $('#fp_gallery').children('img:first');
                if (newimg.width() > newimage.height()) {
                    jQuery('#fp_preview').css({
                        height: "100%",
                        width: ""
                    });
                }
                else if (newimg.height() > newimage.width()) {
                    jQuery('#fp_preview').css({
                        height: "",
                        width: "100%"
                    });

                }
                $newimg.insertBefore($currImage);
                $loader.hide();
                //expand clone
                $theClone.animate({
                    'opacity': 0,
                    'top': windowH / 2 + 'px',
                    'left': windowW / 2 + 'px',
                    'margin-top': '-200px',
                    'margin-left': -final_w / 2 + 'px',
                    'width': final_w + 'px',
                    'height': '400px'
                }, 1000, function() {
                    $(this).remove();
                });
                //now we have two large images on the page
                //fadeOut the old one so that the new one gets shown
                $currImage.fadeOut(2000, function() {
                    $(this).remove();
                });
                //show the navigation arrows
                showNav();
            }).attr('src', $elem.attr('alt'));
        });
        //hide the thumbs container
        hideThumbs();
        e.preventDefault();
    });


    //clicking on the "show thumbs"
    //displays the thumbs container and hides
    //the navigation arrows
    $btn_thumbs.bind('click', function() {
        showThumbs(500);
        hideNav();
    });

    function hideThumbs() {
        $('#outer_container').stop().animate({
            'bottom': '-160px'
        }, 500);
        showThumbsBtn();
    }

    function showThumbs(speed) {
        $('#outer_container').stop().animate({
            'bottom': '0px'
        }, speed);
        hideThumbsBtn();
    }

    function hideThumbsBtn() {
        $btn_thumbs.stop().animate({
            'bottom': '-50px'
        }, 500);
    }

    function showThumbsBtn() {
        $btn_thumbs.stop().animate({
            'bottom': '0px'
        }, 500);
    }

    function hideNav() {
        $btn_next.stop().animate({
            'right': '-50px'
        }, 500);
        $btn_prev.stop().animate({
            'left': '-50px'
        }, 500);
    }

    function showNav() {
        $btn_next.stop().animate({
            'right': '0px'
        }, 500);
        $btn_prev.stop().animate({
            'left': '0px'
        }, 500);
    }

    //events for navigating through the set of images
    $btn_next.bind('click', showNext);
    $btn_prev.bind('click', showPrev);

    //the aim is to load the new image,
    //place it before the old one and fadeOut the old one
    //we use the current variable to keep track which
    //image comes next / before


    function showNext() {
        ++current;
        var $e_next = $thumbScroller.find('.content:nth-child(' + current + ')');
        if ($e_next.length == 0) {
            current = 1;
            $e_next = $thumbScroller.find('.content:nth-child(' + current + ')');
        }
        $loader.show();
        $('<img class="fp_preview"/>').load(function() {
            var $newimg = $(this);
            var $currImage = $('#fp_gallery').children('img:first');
            $newimg.insertBefore($currImage);
            $loader.hide();
            $currImage.fadeOut(2000, function() {
                $(this).remove();
            });
        }).attr('src', $e_next.find('img').attr('alt'));
    }

    function showPrev() {
        --current;
        var $e_next = $thumbScroller.find('.content:nth-child(' + current + ')');
        if ($e_next.length == 0) {
            current = nmb_thumbs;
            $e_next = $thumbScroller.find('.content:nth-child(' + current + ')');
        }
        $loader.show();
        $('<img class="fp_preview"/>').load(function() {
            var $newimg = $(this);
            var $currImage = $('#fp_gallery').children('img:first');
            $newimg.insertBefore($currImage);
            $loader.hide();
            $currImage.fadeOut(2000, function() {
                $(this).remove();
            });
        }).attr('src', $e_next.find('img').attr('alt'));
    }

    function makeScrollable() {
        $(document).bind('mousemove', function(e) {
            var top = (e.pageY - $(document).scrollTop() / 2);
            $(document).scrollTop(top);
        });
    }
}); 
< /script>
```

And the .css

```
img.fp_preview{
position:absolute;
left:0px;
top:0px;
width:0%;  /*if the image is taller than it is wide, make this 100%*/
height:0%; /*if the image is wider than it is tall, make this 100%*/
}
```

Thanks in advance.  Also, this is based on this codrops tutorial:
http://tympanus.net/codrops/2010/09/08/full-page-image-gallery/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know it's a long time since the previous answers but I did manage to get this working.

```
if($newimg.height() > $newimg.width()){

$newimg.addClass('fp_preview1');

}
else
{
$newimg.addClass('fp_preview2');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try using

```
if($newimg.width() > $newimage.height())
```

instead of

```
if(newimg.width()>newimage.height())
```

$ sign here is not same as in PHP or JQuery identifier. $ is a regular string character here so $newimg and newimg are two different variables.

Comment: Something about this if statement is prevent it from finishing loading... Whenever I add in an if statement it pulls up the loading icon, but then just seems to stop.  It's been doing this with every variation on the if statement I've tried....   What is the deal with the $ anyway?  what does it signify?  (like I said, really new at this)

Comment: What I suspect is setting CSS width and height to 0% makes .width() and .height() to return always 0. Means none of the if statements execute. Either try to make one if statement with >= or delete the second if and leave only else

Comment: no luck sadly.  Still having the problem with the image not loading..

Also, for now I'm leaving them blank, not setting them to 0%.  I found a way to make this work closer to what I wanted, it just scrolls in both directions instead of one... I'd prefer it to only scroll in one direction if at all possible though.

Comment: how is your makeScrollable function?

Comment: @Ergec

function makeScrollable(){
     $(document).bind('mousemove',function(e){
      var hiddenY = $(document).height() - $(window).height();

      var hiddenX = $(document).width() - $(window).width();


      var top = (e.pageY/$(window).height())*hiddenY;

      var left = (e.pageX/$(window).height())*hiddenX;

      
      $(document).scrollTop(top);
      $(document).scrollLeft(left);

                    });

    }

This isn't producing the smooth scrolling I thought it would though...